# How do I fix issues with IBM Watson Image Recognition upload error? Screenshot of the error attached for reference

Tags: ibm-watson, image-recognition, watson-studio

How do I fix issues with IBM Watson Image Recognition upload error? Screenshot of the error attached for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

413 is payload too large. From the API docs

> The size of the image file in the request is larger than the maximum supported size.

I suggest you use a smaller image.